# how to load Dictionary data in UITableViewCell in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, dictionary

Here i am getting data in xml and i have retrieved into `Dictionary` to load in `tableView`. Work flow - When user in home screen and taps on create button and it takes to next search product screen there user can able their amazon products. searched product are loaded into table view cell.

My issue is when taps on create button `tableView` tries to load data and its getting crash

Crash line is results!.count.

Here is the code i tried:

```
 var results: [[String: String]]?
 var currentDictionary: [String: String]? // the current dictionary
 var currentValue: String?                // the current value for one of the 
 keys in the dictionary
 let recordKey = "ItemAttributes"
 let dictionaryKeys = Set<String>(["Title"])

  func parserDidStartDocument(_ parser: XMLParser) {
    results = []
  }

// start element
//
// - If we're starting a "record" create the dictionary that will hold the results
// - If we're starting one of our dictionary keys, initialize `currentValue` (otherwise leave `nil`)

func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {
    if elementName == recordKey {
        currentDictionary = [:]
    } else if dictionaryKeys.contains(elementName) {
        currentValue = ""
    }
  }

// found characters
//
// - If this is an element we care about, append those characters.
// - If `currentValue` still `nil`, then do nothing.

func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
    currentValue? += string
}

// end element
//
// - If we're at the end of the whole dictionary, then save that dictionary in our array
// - If we're at the end of an element that belongs in the dictionary, then save that value in the dictionary

func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
    if elementName == recordKey {
        results!.append(currentDictionary!)
        currentDictionary = nil
    } else if dictionaryKeys.contains(elementName) {
        currentDictionary![elementName] = currentValue
        currentValue = nil
    }
 }

// Just in case, if there's an error, report it. (We don't want to fly blind here.)

func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, parseErrorOccurred parseError: Error) {
    print(parseError)

    currentValue = nil
    currentDictionary = nil
    results = nil
 }

//         func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
//            return 1
//        }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return results!.count
   }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! amazonProductListTableViewCell

    let productlist = ProductName[indexPath.row]
    print("prodic:::\(productlist)")

    //        cell.amazonProductTitle?.text = productlist[indexPath.row]

    //        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = book.bookAuthor

    return cell
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never declare a table view datasource array as optional.

If `numberOfRows` is called before the array has been initialized the app crashes.

Declare `results`

```
var results = [[String: String]]()
```

In `parserDidStartDocument` as well as in `parseErrorOccurred` clear the array

```
results.removeAll()
```

---

Consider that every force unwrapped optional can cause a crash and you are using a lot of exclamation marks!

Comment: Thanks for answering!! yeah i did that but how to list in table view cell..Can you help me out this pls

Comment: In `cellForRow` get the item for index path from the array `let item = results[indexPath.row]` and extract the values for the desired keys. It's highly recommended to use a custom struct or class rather than a dictionary.

Comment: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return results.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! amazonProductListTableViewCell

        let item = results[indexPath.row]
        print("prodic:::\(item)")

                cell.amazonProductTitle?.text = item["Title"]


        return cell
    }

Comment: You have to call `reloadData()` on the table view after parsing the data.

Comment: "*Never declare a table view datasource array as optional*" - I do that all of the time. It lets my table view tell the difference between "the data isn't loaded yet" and "there is no data". Of course I don't blindly force-unwrap the optional either.

Comment: @rmaddy From the perspective of the naive viewer what is the difference between *no data* and *not loaded yet*? In both cases you will see an empty table view 

Comment: But that's the incorrect assumption. "Not loaded yet" may not lead to an empty table.